# Ошибка при создании таблицы через Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

[image: Выводится ошибка при создании таблицы и полей в ней]

Читал много статей по этому вопросу но либо они устарели либо у меня другая ошибка -_-

[image]

Comment: а если добавить префикс, допустим `tbl_`?

Comment: Уже был подобный вопрос. Проблема не с `Hibernate` (так как при запуске таблицы создаются), а с `Intellij IDEA Inspection`

Comment: Или у Вас не создаётся таблице при запуске приложения?

Comment: При запуске вылетает ошибка 
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like '@'JoinTable or '@'JoinColumn: entity.User.transactions

Answer (score 0):

`transaction` это зарезервированное слово и его не можно использовать. Измените как-то имя на другое.

Comment: Не вышло. Он не хочет принимать любые новые таблицы кроме первой которую я создал

Comment: @RedCape а можете скинуть тогда хотя бы само описание ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки которые были в коде:
1) Ошибки в расстановке аннотации @ManyToOne @OneToMany
2) Лишняя аннотация @JoinColumn перед полем `private Set<Transaction> transactions;`